# Google Analytics Management API 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I have an application which gets Google Analytics metadata and statistics for a couple dozens google users from Management and Reporting API.

Everything was ok for a long period (several month), but yesterday around 21:00 pm UTC one of them (user) started getting this error: 500, Backend Error or sometimes InternalError

His Management API requests:
get all Accounts response is 200 with with 360 items
get all WebProperties response is 200 with 170 items
get all Profiles response is 200 with 1000 items
get all Goals response is 500 with error [should be 1000 items, but error now]

And still getting this error for now (More than 24 hours).

By the way, Reporting API for this client works fine too (for one of his view/profile)

What i researched:
I've tried to request goals not for all, but for one specific account > specific property > specific profile, and api response is 200 OK! in this case!
Earlier request goals for all profiles worked fine, for a long period! But not today.

Comment: You sould submit and [Bug report](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list) if you are getting a consistent 500 error with all your account Ids. Request details and request response.

Comment: I've been getting the same response for Goals as well it started some time before 12:00 UTC. asp.net shop here, we're using the Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 package in nuget Version 1.16.0.582 but really seems like it's on google's end.

Comment: Matt, ty! I made a bug report here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36546357

Answer (score 3):

500 and 503 errors are basically sever load errors. The server that is processing your request took to long to process your request so it timed out.  You need to remember that you are not the only one accessing a server. It could very easily be something that another developer was running that slowed down your request and resulted in an error.

You should implement [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors#backoff) and just try the request again.

*Top tip: would be to not run on the hour you are competing with everyone that has a cron job set to run. Also running at midnight west cost USA is when everyone's quotas reset also a not a good time to be hitting the server.*

**Update:**

The team would like to suggest that you post an issue on the issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400).  The management API team can have a look at it.  Add your account info from Google Developer console.  I would add the profile in question.  Link the issue back here and I will send it to them.

If you are running the following request I think you should stop that's really not meant for returning huge numbers.

```
analytics.Management.Goals.List("~all", "~all", "~all");
```

Comment: DalmTo, when i faced 500 or 503, i retry it only once and it not helps for this user (for others it helps). I'll try to change my code to make retry more than once and i'll be back here soon with news about results... I should remind you that this problem persists last 24 hours without  even a single 200 response! My update cycle for each user is 10 minutes delay (6 times per hour)

Comment: Check out how to implement Exponential Backoff.  However if this is something that just happens today then i would lean towards it being an outage on the server your user is connecting to.    Looks like there have been a few outages to day https://status.cloud.google.com/ https://status.cloud.google.com/ but its hard to tell which system it could be linked to.    If adding backoff doesn't help and it still doesn't work tomorrow i can contact the team and see if they can detect anything on their end.

Comment: DalmTo, i implemented exponentioal backoff two month ago already. It worked fine always and now for others too.

Comment: This sounds like an outage to me.  Something local to that single user.  It wouldn't be the first time I have seen that.   However I can send off an email but it will be a while before we hear from them they are west cost USA.

Comment: I've changed my code to make it 3 retries, you can see here timing of my exponential backoff from logs:  
14:17:25.827: first Request - get goals - Response 500,  
14:17:48.048: 1st retry - Response 500,  
14:18:06.227: 2d retry - Response 500,  
14:18:31.477: 3rd retry - Response 500.  
I want to remind you - his Accounts,Webproperties,Profiles(views) - responses is 200. But not goals of all accounts,properties,profiles.. especially now and last 24 hours+ :(

Comment: DalmTo, send an email if u can, thank you very much!

Comment: I did but like I said it will be a while and I cant guarantee they will respond.

Comment: I have heard back from the team.

Answer (score 0):

So on a hunch I found a solution that seems to work. 
This would fail (very simplified):

```
var goalsList = analytics.Management.Goals.List("~all", "~all", "~all");
var goalsResult = goalsList.Execute();
```

That all, all, all reminded me of some problem I had on our platform. So I tried to limit my goal requests a bit. The first is accountId so I got all of our accounts and then looped over them pulling the set of goals for each.

This seems to work.

```
...
var accountIds = GetAccountIds(analytics); 
foreach (var a in accountIds)
{
     do
     {
         var goalsList = analytics.Management.Goals.List(a, "~all", "~all");
...
```

Comment: Joseph, your example really could work, BUT in this case it is too much requests! My user have got 360 accounts for now, with Goals.List("~all", "~all", "~all") i made one request at all, instead of 360 requests for each accountId.

Comment: ("~all", "~all", "~all") Is never a good idea on large accounts.

Comment: DalmTo, that idea is missing in documentation, not even one word about that, but i will try to split in a half his accounts, ok... It seems uncomfortable, but I will try it.

Comment: Felsher70, I understand why you'd think making that many requests isn't a great idea, but it seems google is just blocking Goals.List("~all", "~all", "~all") now. I'm guessing because some Jobs are too large. I inherited the code base I'm working with or I'd try to pull the Goals per property when I need them. 

This is working for me just write the loop and get your software working. I was able to verify I'm getting all the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by google team on their side! Thank you!